# Can someone explain this parameter?

Tags: web-services, url, parameters, upload

I was reading [5haked's research blog](https://5haked.blogspot.in/2016/10/how-i-hacked-pornhub-for-fun-and-profit.html).

And it contained this particular part:

[image]

What is:

```
"@type":["GorillaHub\\SDK\\SDKBundle\\V0001\\ExceptionTransmitter"]
```

I have never seen this type of URL or parameter before. Google doesn't return any results.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that it’s part of the content? They could output whatever they want in there (something in a known syntax, something in their own proprietary syntax, natural langauge, non-sensical strings etc.). Not sure how an answer what kind of content/format this is could be helpful … Do you know of JSON?